# Django + Celery + Pytest - Pytest.celery.worker not working

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a project setup with:

```
Django 1.8
Celery 4.1
Pytest with Celery fixtures
```

I´m trying to create a test where I can assert a certain task is consumed by a worker but apparently the worker never consume the task unless I explicitly call it´s `start()` method:

```
import pytest
from exchangesm9.celery_task import app, treat_ticket_callback

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def celery_app():
    return app

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def celery_worker_parameters():
    return {
        'queues': ('treat-ticket-callback', ),
    }

def test_treat_ticket_callback_is_serialized_and_dispatch_to_worker(
        celery_worker, celery_app):
    ticket_callback = {
        'external_ticket_code': 4098,
        'status': {
            'id': TICKET_STATUS_ERROR
        }
    }
    ref_num = ticket_callback['external_ticket_code']
    task_info = treat_ticket_callback.delay(ticket_callback)
```

At this point the task will keep on state PENDING 
unless I explicitly invoke `worker.start()`, which will 
make the worker consume the task in the current thread,
blocking the entire process. The only way to 'unblock' it is using ctrl + c.

As celery states:

> celery_worker - Embed live worker.
>
> This fixture starts a Celery worker instance that you can use for
>   integration tests. The worker will be started in a separate thread and
>   will be shutdown as soon as the test returns.

So how should I configure the worker to automatically consume my task on the separated thread instead of manually calling `start()` and blocking my process ?

Comment: Where do you define `treat_ticket_callback` in your test code? It's not imported. What is the purpose of the `celery_app` fixture? Maybe it intefers with the celery_worker? There's also a `celery_app` provided by the pytest celery plugin. I would avoid defining your own fixture with the same name.

Comment: I just forgot to import `treat_ticket_callback` on my sample. I´m redefining my own `celery_app` fixture so it will use my own `celery APP`, where my settings are already configured. (broker/result_backend_url, tasks, routes, etc)

Comment: Are you sure that can be combined with the regular celery pytest fixtures? The docs says that you should use various test fixture functions to configure celery in the tests.

Comment: Your celery_app might not be compatible with the celery_worker fixture. I suggest configuring celery as explained in the celery docs instead.

Comment: After a few hours of messing around it was a pretty simple mistake. My tasks were configured as `ignore_result=True` making they `AsyncResult` instance never update its `.state` attribute